# The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, nltk, numpy-ndarray

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (56, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

[pycharm console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVRXA.png)

```py
# create training data
training = []
# create empty array for classes
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
# training set, bag of words for each sentence
for document in documents:
    # initialize bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = document[0]
    # lemmatize each word
    pattern_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
    # create orur bag of words array with 1 if word match found in current pattern
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in pattern_words else bag.append(0)
    # output is 0 for each tag and 1 for current tag (for each pattern)
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])
# shuffle our features and turn into np.array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)
# create train and test lists. X - patterns, Y - intents
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

# create model - 3 layers. First layer 128 neurons, second layer 64 neurons
# 3rd output layer contains number of neurons
# equal to number of intents to predicct output intent with softmax
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"))

sgd = gradient_descent_v2.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])

hist = model.fit(
    np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1
)
model.save("chatbot_model.h5", hist)
print("Done")
'''
```

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste it to your question and format it as code.

Comment: The list used in this line, `np.array(training)`, has elements that differ in shape as described by the error message.